# Conditional render of super index with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-rendering, react-class-based-component

I'm having a hard time trying to achieve this approach:

I have to add a super index number only in some list items depending on their ID.

What I is when product with id 198940 and 20084 both exist will render 198940 with superIndex 1 and 20084 with superIndex 2.

In the case that only  id 198940 exist  id 198940 will have superIndex 1
In the case that only id 20084 exist 20084  will have superIndex 1.

At the moment Only works when Both ID'S exist and also when only id 198940 exist.

Here's where I got the logic:

````
  /**
   *  Component constructor.
   */
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)





    this.state = {
      active: false,
      superIndex1: null,
      superIndex2: null



    }

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { activeUserProducts } = this.props;
    let index1 = null;
    let index2 = null;
  
    if (activeUserProducts.products.some(p => p.id === 198940)) {
      index1 = 1;
      if (activeUserProducts.products.some(p => p.id === 20084)) {
        index2 = 2;
      }
    } else if (activeUserProducts.products.some(p => p.id === 20084)) {
      index1 = 1;
    }
  
    this.setState({
      superIndex1: index1,
      superIndex2: index2
    });
  } ```    

And I need to render it in a child component where I pass superIndex1 and superIndex2 as props:
````

```
<h4 className='wallets__table__label wallets__table__label--xxl'>
                          {product.title} 
    {product.id === 198940 && props.superIndex.superIndex1 && <sup>{props.superIndex.superIndex1}</sup>}
    {product.id === 20084 && props.superIndex.superIndex2 && <sup>{props.superIndex.superIndex2}</sup>}
```

```

Hope you guys can help me , I've been trying all day to get this done. Thanks!